# Adding a WHERE condition on an IF alias in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble adding a condition on aliases `is_paid`, `is_overdue` and `is_outstanding` in the following query:

```
SELECT r.doc_number,
       r.doc_date,
       r.due_date,
       r.currency,
       r.amount,
       r.vat,
       r.vatammount,
       (r.amount + r.vatammount) final_amount,
       r.currency,
       b.boq_id,
       b.boq_comp_id,
       b.boq_client_id,
       b.boq_agency,
       b.boq_date,
       b.boq_orders,
       b.receivable_id,
       c.comp_name,
       crm.`cn-name-first`,
       crm.`cn-name-last`,
       bi.inv_path,

  (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved)
   FROM receivables_payments
   WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id) total_amount_received,
       IF (r.amount + r.vatammount =
             (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved)
              FROM receivables_payments
              WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id),
           '1',
           '0') AS is_paid,
          IF (CURRENT_DATE >= r.due_date
              AND r.amount + r.vatammount !=
                (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved)
                 FROM receivables_payments
                 WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id),
                  '1',
                  '0') AS is_overdue,
             IF (r.due_date < CURRENT_DATE
                 AND r.amount + r.vatammount !=
                   (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved)
                    FROM receivables_payments
                    WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id),
                     '1',
                     '0') AS is_outstanding
FROM receivables r
LEFT JOIN boq b ON b.receivable_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN boq_invoices bi ON bi.inv_boq_id = b.boq_id
LEFT JOIN comp_companies c ON c.comp_id = b.boq_comp_id
LEFT JOIN crm_contacts crm ON crm.contact_id = b.boq_client_id
WHERE r.status = 'active'
  AND r.doc_type = 'inv'
  AND b.boq_status = 'active'
  AND is_paid = '1'
ORDER BY r.doc_date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Is there any way to modify this query and to make it possible to add a condition on those three aliases?

Answer (score 1):

use alias in where condition .. is not allowed  . because .is not possibile

the query code is evaluted based on a specified  order .. starting from `FROM` then 
`WHERE`   clause and last the `SELECT` and the column alias so .. when the where is performed  the column alias is not available at the query

You could  try with an having condition because having work on the result of the query and not on the raw rows value ..  (this could have effect on performance ..because all the query is performed and only the result is filtered by having)